# call function on button click does not work

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to call a function on button click event . The function is defined in another js file and I have `enqueue` that file in my `function.php` file. I can see that the file has been loaded from `enqueue`. But I got error

> errorReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

when I click on that button. I want to display dropdown menu on that button click

```
<button onclick="jQuery(document).ready(function($) {myFunction();});" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

custom.js

```
(function( $ ) {

    function myFunction() {

        document.getElementById( 'myDropdown' ).classList.toggle( 'show' );

    }

    window.onclick = function( event ) { 

        if ( !event.target.matches( '.dropbtn' ) ) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName( 'dropdown-content' );
        var i;

            for ( i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++ ) {

                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];

                if ( openDropdown.classList.contains( 'show' ) ) {

                    openDropdown.classList.remove( 'show' );

                } 

            } 

        }

    }

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Just write `myFunction` from outside to `$(function() {})`. and your anchor attribute should be `onclick=return myFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the scope of the function, for more detailed explanation refer [this link](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/). To resolve it, try to call the function within the js file itself. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction(){
    ...
    }

    $(".dropbtn").click(myFunction());
});
```

Comment: same issue displayed

Comment: Are you sure you placed both the function and call, inside the same jQuery function?

Comment: Try referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067887/function-is-not-defined-uncaught-referenceerror and other similar questions. Its an easy fix, but you just need to know the key.

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction(){
        alert ('Say something!');
    }

    $(".dropbtn").click(function(){
        myFunction();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you do not need to use the `ready` function in the `onclick` attribute of the button, therefore this will suffice:

```
<button onclick="myFunction();" class="dropbtn">
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Instead of doing this however, you can remove that `onclick` attribute from the button (it is good practice to avoid inline scripts, for code maintainability and security reasons) and try the solution Manikiran suggested you, but with one small difference, you define `myFunction` but **do not execute** it in the `custom.js`:

```
jQuery(function(){
  function myFunction(){
    jQuery( '#myDropdown' ).toggle( 'show' ); //this is the jQuery way
  }

  // remaining code of your custom.js

  jQuery(".dropbtn").click(myFunction); // binds the click event to
                                        // all the buttons with the dropbtn class
});
```

<sup>I noticed you do not use the `$` in some parts, you can replace them all with the `jQuery` keyword.</sup>