# Onclick function not called when its inside a load event listener

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, addeventlistener

I want to make sure my javascript work only after all content is loaded. So, I put my code inside a load event listener. If I create a function inside that event, and try to call it in a onclick event, in a button, I got a error saying my function is not defined.

**Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick**

If I remove the function from the load event, it works. Why this happens?

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="sayHello()">Say Hello</button>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", async () => {

    function sayHello(){
        alert("Hello!");
    }

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function is not defined - uncaught referenceerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067887/function-is-not-defined-uncaught-referenceerror)

Comment: Either don’t declare functions inside the `load` listener or bind the `click` event listener inside it, too. Consider using `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load`, [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212) using attributes like `onclick`. Why is your listener an `async` function?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Thanks for the answer! I tried `DOMContentLoaded`, but I got the same error. My listener is an `async` because some await imports I'll use. Why is a bad idea use `onclick`?

Comment: The solution wasn’t `DOMContentLoaded`; it was the first sentence. Inline event handlers like `onclick` or `oninput` are [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.
in this model we do not assign the `click` function until the `DOMContentLoaded` event is triggered.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('.sayHello').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Hi'))
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="sayHello">Say Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!